# rsync with ssh without using credentials stored in ~/.ssh/config

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I have a script that transfers files. Everytime I run it It needs to connect to a different host. That's why I'm adding the host as parameter.

The script is executed as: `./transfer.sh <hostname>`

```
#!/bin/bash -evx

SSH="ssh \
-o UseRoaming=no \
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i ~/.ssh/privateKey.pem \
-l ec2-user \
${1}"

files=(
  file1
  file2
)

files="${files[@]}"

# this works
$SSH

# this does not work
rsync -avzh --stats --progress $files -e $SSH:/home/ec2-user/

# also this does not work
rsync -avzh --stats --progress $files -e $SSH ec2-user@$1:/home/ec2-user/
```

I can properly connect with the ssh connection stored in `$SSH`, but the rsync connection attempts fails because of the wrong key:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

What would be the correct syntax for the rsync connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `set -x` before the `rsync` line and watch how the arguments are expanded. I believe it will be wrong.

You need to enclose the `ssh` command with arguments (without hostname) into the quotes, otherwise the arguments will get passed to the `rsync` command and not to the `ssh`.

Comment: You were right, $SSH needs to be encapsulated. Accepting this answer as correct since you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

My solution after Jakuje pointed me in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/bash -evx

host=$1

SSH="ssh \
-o UseRoaming=no \
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i ~/.ssh/privateKey.pem \
-l ec2-user"

files=(
  file1
  file2
)

files="${files[@]}"

# transfer all in one rsync connection
rsync -avzh --stats --progress $files -e "$SSH" $host:/home/ec2-user/

# launch setup script
$SSH $host ./setup.sh
```